# Linux doesn't recognize windows on installation

Tags: linux, system-installation, windows, dual-boot

I want to install Linux besides my Windows 7. But when I get into the installation menu, it tells me that this "pc doesn't have an OS installed". Although I already have a Win7 installed. I have 5 partitions from the same disk on my PC, but even `testdisk` shows only one partition.

Here is what I see under win7:

[image]

I googled for it 3 days, and no solution is right to me. That is why I ask here. I tried when installing ubuntu and centos, and both of them don't show me the Win7.

This is what `sudo fdisk -l` gives:

[image]

And here what `gparted` gives:

[image]

I also tried this command:

```
root@ubuntu:~# os-prober
/dev/sda1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Comment: This is a fine question for this site, but it is lacking some important detail. Please run a live-cd (or thumbdrive) and boot but don't install the distro. Once you can get a shell, run `sudo fdisk -l` and add that partition listing into your question.

Comment: I'm not sure but are you on `UEFI` system?

Comment: Dear Dantosso, I fixed your post last time. You can use linux, you can ask a question on understandable English, I don't believe you can't use your shift or "." key as it is needed.

Comment: well, thanks for the edit peterh but I'm not writing a java or whatever language code here and that's why I don't use shift and all this stuff
plus I think that the important is to pass the ide and resolve the probleme so people including me can benefit, and I judge that the idea is clearly understandble but I will make the effort the next time so as I said previously "SORRY"

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've seen Grub2 boot Windows very well.
For a dual-boot, I would recommend installing EasyBCD on the Windows side and it should recognize all the OSes on the system.  I've used it for 3 years on a dual-boot Windows and Fedora Linux system without any issues.